# Cannot create MySQL database with name '5e370227_db'

Tags: mysql

Why am I getting error when I try to create database with name '5e370227_db'?

I am getting the following error:

```
mysql> create database 5e370227_db;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '5e370227_db' at line 1
```

When I try to create a database with name '5a370227_db' (e -> a) it is created successfully:

```
mysql> create database 5a370227_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

Details:

- MYSQL: mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.73, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
- Linux Centos 2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64
- logged as root
- database admin

Comment: A SQL identifier is not allowed to start with a number. You must quote the name: `"5e370227_db"` or using MySQL's dreaded backticks: `\`5e370227_db\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting problem and I think that I've figured it out.

For some reason, MySQL interprets 1e_a_number_ as an exponent - i.e. 10 to the power of something. 1a_a_number has no mathematical meaning, therefore it's not parsed as being a number and accepted as valid. If you notice at the beginning of my experiments below - pure numbers aren't allowed as database/schema names.

Congratulations - it looks like you've spotted a MySQL bug.

Something like this (underscore following number and e) works.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> create schema 1_e34343_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
MariaDB [(none)]>
```

which appears to confirm my conclusion.

This does also - i.e. 1ex works, but 1e1 fails.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> create schema 1ex;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create schema 1e1;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1e1' at line 1
MariaDB [(none)]>
```

=== Experiments leading me to my conclusion ============

```
MariaDB [(none)]> create schema 5e370227_db;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '5e370227_db' at line 1
MariaDB [(none)]> create database 5e370227_db;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '5e370227_db' at line 1
MariaDB [(none)]> create schema  5a370227_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> drop schema  5a370227_db;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database  5a370227_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> drop database  5a370227_db;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database 100;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '100' at line 1
MariaDB [(none)]> create database 100_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database 1000_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database 10000_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database 100000_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database 1000000_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database 10000000_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database 100000000_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database 1000000000_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database 10000000000_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database 100000000000_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database 1000000000000_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database 10000000000000_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database 100000000000000_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database 1000000000000000_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database 10000000000000000_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database 100000000000000000_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database 10000000000000000000000_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database 10000000000000000000000000000000000_db;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> create database 1e0000000000000000000000000000000000_db;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1e0000000000000000000000000000000000_db' at line 1
MariaDB [(none)]> create database 1e000000000000000_db;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1e000000000000000_db' at line 1
MariaDB [(none)]> create database 1e0000000000_db;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1e0000000000_db' at line 1
MariaDB [(none)]> create database 1e4_db;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1e4_db' at line 1
MariaDB [(none)]> create database 1e4_zx;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1e4_zx' at line 1
MariaDB [(none)]> 
MariaDB [(none)]> create database 1a4_zx;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried to create a new defect to mysql: http://bugs.mysql.com/75700

Comment: +1 for solid sleuthing but it's [not an entirely unknown issue](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html) (as was also noted in the bug report).  The same exception applies to usernames, and any reserved word used as an identifier.  The workaround, in any of these cases, is backticks.  I would wager against this being fixed any time soon, and plan to use the backticks, or prefix the databases with a character, instead.

Comment: Thanks for that (the +1 and the docco). Saves me going to the bother of reporting it - would have been my first MySQL bug <sob, sob...>. Oops, just noticed Felix's report - it's annoying,but not mission critical as they point out.